# When importing obj files, the vertex indices order is changed. Is there any way to solve it?

Tags: indexing, indices, vertex

[This is part of my obj file. The goal is to create indices in the order of the vertices.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/juBxH.jpg)

[The coordinates of the index of the 0th vertex of the blender do not match the 0th vertex of the obj file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XoN3M.jpg)

It was confirmed that the vertex of the first line in the obj file is assigned an index of 523 in the blender. Is there a way to generate the indices in the order of the vertices of the obj file? Or is there a way to specify the vertex indices in the obj file format?

Answer (score 3):

The solution with Blender 2.9 is quite easy :

1. Import your .obj, that is `File -> Import -> Wavefront (.obj)`
2. In the `Blender file View`, click on the file you want to import
3. Open the `Geometry` panel, click on `Keep Vert Order`;
4. click Import OBJ

Now the vertices ID should match the .obj indices.

[image]